# Yii2 Filters with Sqldataprovider

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2, csqldataprovider

I have following code in my search() function of search model. Data is displaying correctly in gridview but i'm not able to use searching functions of gridview.

```
public function search($params)
    {

        $totalCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patient_test')->queryScalar();

        $query = new Query();
        $query->select('patient.id as id,patient_test.receipt_number,patient.name as patient_id, GROUP_CONCAT(test_group.name) as test_group_id, patient.age as patient_test_age')
            ->from('patient_test');
        $query->join = [
            ['LEFT JOIN', 'patient', 'patient_test.patient_id = patient.id'],
            ['LEFT JOIN', 'test_group', 'patient_test.test_group_id = test_group.id']];
        $query->groupBy(['patient_test.patient_id', 'patient_test.receipt_number', 'patient_test.is_sample_received', 'patient_test.is_ready']);


            $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
//                'db' => Yii::$app->db,
                'sql' => $query->createCommand()->sql,
                'totalCount' => $totalCount,
                'sort' => [
                    'attributes' => [
                        'patient_id' => [
                            'desc' => ['patient_id' => SORT_DESC ],
                            'default' => SORT_DESC,
                        ],
                    ],
                ], 'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => $pagination,
                ]
            ]);


        $this->load($params);


        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }


        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'is_sample_received' => $this->is_sample_received,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patient_test.receipt_number', $this->receipt_number])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patient.name', $this->patient_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'test_group.name', $this->test_group_id])

->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patient.age', $this->patient_test_age])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patient.mobile_no', $this->patient_test_mobile]);


            return $dataProvider;
        }
```

from this, my code is working fine but filtration/searching not working

Comment: is your data valid? $this->validate() on line 32 returns true?

Comment: it does't go in that condition so it means data is valid

Comment: @scaisEdge please help

Comment: @ekaratas i have figure out some error. 

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

paramter is not bounding in andfilterwere...